# MYSQL - get average value if count more than 1

Tags: php, mysql

i have tables as follows

```
+------+------------+--------+----------+-----------+--------------------+---------+--------------------+------+
| mrId | date_test  | c_load | c_weight | monitorId | strength           | density | str_percent        | age  |
+------+------------+--------+----------+-----------+--------------------+---------+--------------------+------+
|  853 | 2017-02-11 |    100 |     8020 |       124 |  4.444444444444445 |  2.3763 | 11.111111111111112 |    1 |
|  854 | 2017-02-13 |    305 |     7940 |       124 | 13.555555555555555 |  2.3526 |  33.88888888888889 |    3 |
|  855 | 2017-02-17 |    450 |     7910 |       124 |                 20 |  2.3437 |                 50 |    7 |
|  856 | 2017-02-17 |    460 |     8040 |       124 | 20.444444444444443 |  2.3822 |  51.11111111111111 |    7 |
|  857 | 2017-03-10 |    765 |     8020 |       124 |                 34 |  2.3763 |                 85 |   28 |
|  858 | 2017-03-10 |    735 |     8040 |       124 | 32.666666666666664 |  2.3822 |  81.66666666666667 |   28 |
+------+------------+--------+----------+-----------+--------------------+---------+--------------------+------+
```

I want to plot a line graph for each of the strength vs age but the 'age' column contain duplicate data when more than 1 sample tested on the same day.

what query do i need to use if i only want the average strength if the age count is more than 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `GROUP BY` to compute the average strength for those `age` values which appear more than once:

```
SELECT age, AVG(strength) AS avg_strength
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY age
```

Note that we don't even need to include special logic to handle the case where `age` appears more than once, because the average of a single age value is just equal to that single value.

If you want to keep the same number of original points, then you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.age, t2.avg_strength   -- and other columns, if needed
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT age, AVG(strength) AS avg_strength
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY age
) t2
    ON t1.age = t2.age
```

Comment: thats it! thank you!!

Comment: as you explain, the average of a single value is still equal to that single value so the first solution is good enough since i will put a `where` clause to the query to limit to `monitorId` value.